# JQuery progress bar freezing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

Currently, I have a jQuery indeterminate progress bar showing on page load, but freezes while loading page content, then resumes after content is loaded.

Content on the page: 13 dynamic google charts are loaded from information provided by a JSON feed.

The progress bar is using the standard jQuery animated gif.

Here is the code that calls the progress bar:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: false
});
```

It is just a basic progress bar, but I have a feeling that with everything going on on the page, it freezes functionality of everything else, including drop down menus.

What is causing the progress bar to freeze until everything on the page is loaded?

Comment: what version jquery you are using?

Comment: try putting your google chart js (where you init and draw them) at the end of your HTML right before the body tag is closed, so the chart loading not interupting other scripts